# Current decreasing while measuring the current through a constant current source resistor

Tags: resistors, current-measurement, measurement, multimeter, constant-current

My Circuit :

[image]

The above is my circuit.

The Forward drop of LEDs is typically 2.8V and a maximum of 3.15V.
I designed the current through the string to be around 21mA, so the emitter resistor is 33ohms.

Now, while performing the actual measurement, I try to measure the current through the 33ohm resistor using the multimeter (Link attached below).

But what I am getting is that, initially, the current reading that I get from the meter is around 21mA, but if I let it measure for some more time, like for say,1-2 mins, the current reduces to 20mA.

This trend continues. The longer the time I measure the current through the resistor using the multimeter, the current reading keeps on decreasing. I kept the reading ON for like 5 mins and the reading turned out to be around 16mA. I didn't extend beyond that.

But I do not see the intensity of the LEDs decreasing. The Intensity and the brightness of the LEDs are the same (Like if the current through them was actually 21mA. No change in the LED brightness). If I measure the forward voltage of the LEDs, it is around 2.74V.

Any reason why this is happening?

Multimeter Link : [6 and half digital multimeter](https://www.keysight.com/en/pdx-2835291-pn-34460A/digital-multimeter-6-digit-basic-truevolt?cc=IN&lc=eng)

Comment: how are you measuring the current?

Comment: Lifting one end of the resistor, taking two small wires (one from the lifted end of the resistor and the other from the lifted pad) and using the current measurement mode in the multimeter.

Comment: try measuring the current through the LEDs instead

Comment: Ok I will try to measure. But any idea on why this is happening?

Comment: some of the current runs through the second transistor

Comment: My circuit is based on a sample constant current circuit found on the websites. So, I have replicated it in my design. I have two questions as you mentioned that the current runs through the second transistor. 1. What would be the transistor region when you say the current flows through the other transistor (The maximum voltage would be 0.7V and there is not limitation of the base current through it). 2. In such case, even if I measure the current through the LED, it will follow the same trend right?

Comment: @Newbie If your control BJT is warming up, then it's \$V_\text{BE}\$ is decreasing. So the voltage across your 33 ohm resistor decreases, leading to lower LED current. I'd be considering this issue, first.

Comment: I am testing this circuit at 25degC ambient. And the temperature of the Portion of the PCB where this circuit is located is around 105degC

Comment: And please also tell me if there might be something wrong while measuring it with a multimeter in current mode. Is there anything that I need to take care of in current mode measurement of this section?

Comment: Get some freezer spray and spray it on the sense transistor - it is warming up

Comment: At 105C you need some re-design anyway. Either of the circuit, or the heatsinking.  Nearby LEDs will have a shortened life. As @jonk points out, thermal effects will affect your constant current source.

Comment: At 105degC (local PCB temperature), the brightness of the LED is fine. So there is no issue with brightness. I agree if this continues, the life time of the components are shortened. Any solution or tips on how to redesign the circuit or modify it without adding heatsink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All semiconductors (as well as some conductors) [change forward voltage drop depending on temperature.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/181995/why-does-temperature-modify-the-characteristics-of-a-diode)

See which parts are getting warmer, using an infrared thermometer, and put a heat-sink on them (or just heat-sink likely culprits). Don't forget your LED string.

As to why you don't see a difference in brightness, [visual response to light is approximately logarithmic.](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/5408/sensitivity-of-human-eye-to-luminance) The [stellar magnitude scale](https://skyandtelescope.org/astronomy-resources/the-stellar-magnitude-system/) is based on that response. Simply put, you would *barely* notice a difference in brightness by a factor of ~1.4 of two lights, unless they were adjacent. A difference of 20 mA compared to 16 mA, ~20%, would not be apparent.